# Java Android close the camera

Tags: java, android

I used the following code lines for opening a camera:

```
public void TakePhoto(){
    Intent camIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(camIntent,0);

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    CordovaPlugin callback = this.activityResultCallback;
    if (callback != null) {
        callback.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    }

    if (requestCode==0){
        Bitmap camImage = (Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get("data");
        ImageView ivPhoto = null; 
        //ivPhoto.setImageBitmap(camImage);
    }
}
```

in on ActivityResult i want to close the camera , how can i do it?

Comment: the camera should close it's self.. when the user hits back, or takes a picture

Comment: It doesnt close after taking a picture

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
File tempFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                + "/myfolder");
        tempFolder.mkdir();
        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/myfolder",
                String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
```

Comment: Hi it is better, but I still have a problem, After taking a picture the following method is running   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
  
     if (requestCode==0){
         Bitmap camImage = (Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get("data");
         ImageView ivPhoto = null; 
         //ivPhoto.setImageBitmap(camImage);
     } 
                  The problem is that the intent is null... and i cant get the picture data

Comment: on Result, check to see if Result == RESULT_OK  if it does, check for the file you just created, make sure that you have saved the file_path before you started the camera Activity and are storing it using saved instance state incase the device kills your activity to free up memory

Comment: i just added android.provider.MediaStore and it works... Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

Comment: Ah.. makes sense, you would need that.  Can you accept my answer